# How do you restart a Java applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I'm making a game for a school project and have been stuck on this part for a few days. How would I go about restarting the following applet? I have tried to make a `restart()` method, but lack the necessary skills.

```
package main;

import game.framework.Animation;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.lang.Thread.State;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


//add speedboost
public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    enum GameState {
        Running, Dead
    }


    static GameState state = GameState.Running;



private Background bg2, bg1;
private boolean restart = false;    
private Player player;
private SpeedBoost sb1;
private Image image;
private Image backsprite1, backsprite2;
private Image player1, dad1, dad2, dad3;
private Image player2;
private Image player3;
private Image back1;
private Image back2, endscreen;
private Image back3, coin, bigcoin;
 private Image back4, sbimg;
 public Image tilebase, platform;
 private Block block1, block2, block3, block4;
private Coin coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5;
private LargeCoin bc1; 
//use for the base...
private Dad dad;
private Graphics second;
private Animation playwalk, dadwalk;
private URL base;
private Platform plat1, plat2, plat3, plat4, plat5, plat6, plat7;
public static int score = 1, coinsint = 1;
public static String score2, coins = "1";
public static int scorespeed = 1;
public int hs1, hs2, hs3, hs4, hs5, totcoins;
public String hs1s, hs2s, hs3s, hs4s, hs5s, totcoinss;
public Ends ends;
    @Override
        public void init() {
        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
        frame.setTitle("Game v1.2.2");
        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        endscreen = getImage(base, "data/endscreen.png");

        coin = getImage(base, "data/coin.png");
  bigcoin = getImage(base, "data/bigcoin.png");      

tilebase = getImage(base, "data/tilebase.png");
 platform = getImage(base, "data/blocksmall.png");
       back1 = getImage(base, "data/back1.png");
        back2 = getImage(base, "data/back2.png");
        back3 = getImage(base, "data/back3.png");
        back4 = getImage(base, "data/back4.png");`enter code here`

        sbimg = getImage(base, "data/speedboost.png");
        player1 = getImage(base, "data/player1.png");
        player2 = getImage(base, "data/player2.png");
        player3 = getImage(base, "data/player3.png");

        dad1 = getImage(base, "data/dad1.png");
        dad2 = getImage(base, "data/dad2.png");
        dad3 = getImage(base, "data/dad3.png");

        backsprite1 = back1;
        backsprite2 = back2;

        playwalk = new Animation();
      playwalk.addFrame(player1, 80);
      playwalk.addFrame(player2, 80);
      playwalk.addFrame(player3, 80);

dadwalk = new Animation();
dadwalk.addFrame(dad1, 80);
dadwalk.addFrame(dad2, 80);
dadwalk.addFrame(dad3, 80);
    }
public void animate() {
    playwalk.update(15); 
dadwalk.update(15);


    }








@Override
        public void start() {
    state = state.Running;
          ends = new Ends(-3, 0);
                 //create objects at positions

        coin1 = new Coin(-100, -10);
        coin2 = new Coin(-10, -10);
        coin3 = new Coin(-10, -10);
        coin4 = new Coin(-10, -10);
        coin5 = new Coin(-10, -10);

          player = new Player();



          dad = new Dad();

          bg1 = new Background(1, 0);
      bg2 = new Background(2099, 0);

      plat1 = new Platform(0,0);
      plat2 = new Platform(-100,0);
      plat3 = new Platform(-200,0);
      plat4 = new Platform(-300,0);
      plat5 = new Platform(-400,0);
      plat6 = new Platform(-500,0);
      plat7 = new Platform(-600,0);

      sb1 = new SpeedBoost(-100, 0);
      bc1 = new LargeCoin(-99, 0);

      block1 = new Block(0, 0);
      block2 = new Block(0, 0);
      block3 = new Block(0, 0);
      block4 = new Block(0, 0);



      Thread thread = new Thread(this);
          thread.start();
      }




            @Override
                public void stop() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (state == GameState.Running) {
                while (true) {
                    //selecting sprites for the background

                    //updates go here
if(bg1.getBgX() < -2100){
    bg1.setBgX(2100);
}
 if(bg2.getBgX() < -2100){
    bg2.setBgX(2100);
}

 //backgrounds arent working
 if(bg1.getBgX() > 2000){
                           Random rand = new Random();

                            int  nel = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
                             if(nel == 1){
                                backsprite1 = back1;
                             }if(nel == 2){
                                 backsprite1 = back2;
                             }if(nel == 3){
                                 backsprite1 = back3;
                             }if(nel == 4){
                                backsprite1 = back4;
                             }
                    }

                if(bg2.getBgX() > 2000){
                             Random rand = new Random();

                                int  n1 = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
                                 if(n1 == 1){
                                    backsprite2 = back1;
                                 }if(n1 == 2){
                                     backsprite2 = back2;
                                 }if(n1 == 3){
                                     backsprite2 = back3;
                                 }if(n1 == 4){
                                    backsprite2 = back4;
                                 }
                }

                block4.update();
                block3.update();
                block2.update();
                    block1.update();

                    sb1.update();

                    bc1.update();

                    player.update();

                    dad.update();

                    bg1.update();
                   bg2.update();

                   coin1.update();
                   coin2.update();
                   coin3.update();
                   coin4.update();
                   coin5.update();


                   plat1.update();
                    plat2.update();
                    plat3.update();
                    plat4.update();
                    plat5.update();
                    plat6.update();
                    plat7.update();

                    if(Block.lives < 0){
                        state = GameState.Dead;

 }



                    animate();
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(17);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            }
            @Override
            public void update(Graphics g) {
                if (image == null) {
                    image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                    second = image.getGraphics();
                }


            //other updates go here
                block1.update();
                block2.update();
                block3.update();
                block4.update();



                sb1.update();

                bc1.update();

                coin1.update();
                coin2.update();
                coin3.update();
                coin4.update();
                coin5.update();

                plat1.update();
                plat2.update();
                plat3.update();
                plat4.update();
                plat5.update();
                plat6.update();
                plat7.update();

                bg1.update();
                bg2.update();

                player.update();
               dad.update();


                second.setColor(getBackground());
                second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                second.setColor(getForeground());
                paint(second);

                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);


            }


            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                if (state == GameState.Running) {
                //main graphics identifyers here
            // first are drawn below last
                 //need to make the platform lower down, see class for explanation

                    g.drawImage(backsprite1, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(backsprite2, bg2.getBgX(), bg2.getBgY(), this);


                 g.drawImage(playwalk.getImage(), player.getCenterX(), player.getCenterY(), this);

                 g.drawImage(platform, plat1.getCenterX(), plat1.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat2.getCenterX(), plat2.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat3.getCenterX(), plat3.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat4.getCenterX(), plat4.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat5.getCenterX(), plat5.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat6.getCenterX(), plat6.getCenterY(), this);
                    g.drawImage(platform, plat7.getCenterX(), plat7.getCenterY(), this);

                    g.drawImage(sbimg, sb1.getCenterX(), sb1.getCenterY(), this);

                    g.drawImage(bigcoin, bc1.centerX, bc1.centerY, this);

                    g.drawImage(dadwalk.getImage(), dad.centerX, dad.centerY, this);

           g.drawImage(tilebase, block1.getCenterX(), block1.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(tilebase, block2.getCenterX(), block2.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(tilebase, block3.getCenterX(), block3.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(tilebase, block4.getCenterX(), block4.getCenterY(), this);

            g.drawImage(coin, coin1.getCenterX(), coin1.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(coin, coin2.getCenterX(), coin2.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(coin, coin3.getCenterX(), coin3.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(coin, coin4.getCenterX(), coin4.getCenterY(), this);
            g.drawImage(coin, coin5.getCenterX(), coin5.getCenterY(), this);



            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.drawString(score2, 700, 25);
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 36);
            g.setFont(font);

            g.drawString(coins, 20, 25);


            }else if (state == GameState.Dead) {
                totcoins += coinsint;
                coinsint = 0;
                hs1s = String.valueOf(hs1);
                hs2s = String.valueOf(hs2);
                hs3s = String.valueOf(hs3);
                hs4s = String.valueOf(hs4);
                hs5s = String.valueOf(hs5);
                totcoinss = String.valueOf(totcoins);




                if(score > hs1){
                    hs1 = score;
                }else if(score > hs2){
                    hs2 = score;
                }else if(score > hs3){
                        hs3 = score;
                    }else if(score > hs4){
                        hs4 = score;
                    }else if(score > hs5){
                        hs5 = score;
                    }
                scorespeed = 0;
              //format this shit up in here
                //when restart is init, then this will be tested


                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(hs1s, 230, 220);
            g.drawString(hs2s, 230, 250);
            g.drawString(hs3s, 230, 280);
            g.drawString(hs4s, 230, 310);
            g.drawString(hs5s, 230, 340);
           g.drawString(totcoinss, 700, 100);
           g.drawImage(endscreen, ends.cornX, ends.cornY, this);    

            }

            }
    //fix the android stuff







@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

            player.jump();
            Player.jumps += 1;
            break;


        }               
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
if(state == state.Dead){

}   
    }


}

@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public  Background getBg1() {
        return bg1;
    }
    public void setBg1(Background bg1) {
        this.bg1 = bg1;
    }
    public Background getBg2() {
        return bg2;
    }
    public void setBg2(Background bg2) {
        this.bg2 = bg2;
    }
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public Image getBacksprite() {
        return backsprite1;
    }
    public void setBacksprite(Image backsprite) {
        this.backsprite1 = backsprite;
    }
    public Image getBacksprite1() {
        return backsprite1;
    }
    public void setBacksprite1(Image backsprite1) {
        this.backsprite1 = backsprite1;
    }
    public Image getBacksprite2() {
        return backsprite2;
    }
    public void setBacksprite2(Image backsprite2) {
        this.backsprite2 = backsprite2;
    }
    public Image getPlayer1() {
        return player1;
    }
    public void setPlayer1(Image player1) {
        this.player1 = player1;
    }
    public Image getPlayer2() {
        return player2;
    }
    public void setPlayer2(Image player2) {
        this.player2 = player2;
    }
    public Image getPlayer3() {
        return player3;
    }
    public void setPlayer3(Image player3) {
        this.player3 = player3;
    }
    public Image getBack1() {
        return back1;
    }
    public void setBack1(Image back1) {
        this.back1 = back1;
    }
    public Image getBack2() {
        return back2;
    }
    public void setBack2(Image back2) {
        this.back2 = back2;
    }
    public Image getBack3() {
        return back3;
    }
    public void setBack3(Image back3) {
        this.back3 = back3;
    }
    public Image getBack4() {
        return back4;
    }
    public void setBack4(Image back4) {
        this.back4 = back4;
    }
    public Graphics getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    public void setSecond(Graphics second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
    public Animation getPlaywalk() {
        return playwalk;
    }
    public void setPlaywalk(Animation playwalk) {
        this.playwalk = playwalk;
    }
    public URL getBase() {
        return base;
    }
    public void setBase(URL base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public static Image getTilebase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public GameState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(GameState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public SpeedBoost getSb1() {
        return sb1;
    }

    public void setSb1(SpeedBoost sb1) {
        this.sb1 = sb1;
    }

    public Image getCoin() {
        return coin;
    }

    public void setCoin(Image coin) {
        this.coin = coin;
    }

    public Image getSbimg() {
        return sbimg;
    }

    public void setSbimg(Image sbimg) {
        this.sbimg = sbimg;
    }

    public Image getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(Image platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    public Block getBlock1() {
        return block1;
    }

    public void setBlock1(Block block1) {
        this.block1 = block1;
    }

    public Block getBlock2() {
        return block2;
    }

    public void setBlock2(Block block2) {
        this.block2 = block2;
    }

    public Block getBlock3() {
        return block3;
    }

    public void setBlock3(Block block3) {
        this.block3 = block3;
    }

    public Block getBlock4() {
        return block4;
    }

    public void setBlock4(Block block4) {
        this.block4 = block4;
    }

    public Coin getCoin1() {
        return coin1;
    }

    public void setCoin1(Coin coin1) {
        this.coin1 = coin1;
    }

    public Coin getCoin2() {
        return coin2;
    }

    public void setCoin2(Coin coin2) {
        this.coin2 = coin2;
    }

    public Coin getCoin3() {
        return coin3;
    }

    public void setCoin3(Coin coin3) {
        this.coin3 = coin3;
    }

    public Coin getCoin4() {
        return coin4;
    }

    public void setCoin4(Coin coin4) {
        this.coin4 = coin4;
    }

    public Coin getCoin5() {
        return coin5;
    }

    public void setCoin5(Coin coin5) {
        this.coin5 = coin5;
    }

    public Platform getPlat1() {
        return plat1;
    }

    public void setPlat1(Platform plat1) {
        this.plat1 = plat1;
    }

    public Platform getPlat2() {
        return plat2;
    }

    public void setPlat2(Platform plat2) {
        this.plat2 = plat2;
    }

    public Platform getPlat3() {
        return plat3;
    }

    public void setPlat3(Platform plat3) {
        this.plat3 = plat3;
    }

    public Platform getPlat4() {
        return plat4;
    }

    public void setPlat4(Platform plat4) {
        this.plat4 = plat4;
    }

    public Platform getPlat5() {
        return plat5;
    }

    public void setPlat5(Platform plat5) {
        this.plat5 = plat5;
    }

    public Platform getPlat6() {
        return plat6;
    }

    public void setPlat6(Platform plat6) {
        this.plat6 = plat6;
    }

    public Platform getPlat7() {
        return plat7;
    }

    public void setPlat7(Platform plat7) {
        this.plat7 = plat7;
    }

    public static int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public static void setScore(int score) {
        Main.score = score;
    }

    public static int getCoinsint() {
        return coinsint;
    }

    public static void setCoinsint(int coinsint) {
        Main.coinsint = coinsint;
    }

    public static String getScore2() {
        return score2;
    }

    public static void setScore2(String score2) {
        Main.score2 = score2;
    }

    public static String getCoins() {
        return coins;
    }

    public static void setCoins(String coins) {
        Main.coins = coins;
    }

    public static int getScorespeed() {
        return scorespeed;
    }

    public static void setScorespeed(int scorespeed) {
        Main.scorespeed = scorespeed;
    }

    public void setTilebase(Image tilebase) {
        this.tilebase = tilebase;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"making .. a school project"*  1) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: TL/DR; You need to figure out how to reset your program's state back to the beginning. Consider first trying to simplify your code by using arrays or collections as there is **a lot** of unnecessary redundancy that will just make it harder for you or us to debug. Also you'll want to improve your code formatting since doing so will make it easier for us and others to read and understand.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). (No 3rd party APIs, using synthetic images, and *short*).  2) `setSize(800, 480);`  Don'tdo that in an applet.  Ever.  3) *"(sorry i dont know html)"*  To complete this homework, you will need to become familiar with it, at least a little.  The HTML sets the size of an applet and defines where the classes can be found.

Comment: I'd probably start by moving the logic from your `init` and `start` methods so that they would become your basic `restart` method (or a series of methods you can call).  You could always just call `init`, `start` yourself if you really wanted to...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree, but given the overall...tidiness of the code, I was simply offering a possible workaround, all be it, a stupid one

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have to admit, I did not delve *deeply* into that ..787 lines(?!) of code.  The things I saw were all within the top 78 LOC.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I stopped at `extends Applet` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"I agree"*  Comment now deleted, and adapted as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 3):

A good approach might be to use the methods like this:

- `init` (should be called once, and by the browser only).  Set up any common GUI elements and call the `startNewGame()` method.
- `start` (called when the user restores the browser). Un-pause the action (paused in `stop`) and continue the game.
- `stop` pause the current game.
- `startNewGame()` set the initial lives, layout of pieces/characters, score etc.

When the user wants to start a new game, also call `startNewGame()`.

Comment: I'd buy that for a dollar...+1

Comment: @MadProgrammer Heh, hehh..  Love that expression, the concept behind it, and the movie that coined it.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question.

but the format of the applet above seems to be the issue. I would use something basic that would allow more control of the applet.

"Namely using a while(true) is never a good option in my opinion"

```
public class TestAppletCycle extends JApplet implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Init Game
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if(!running) {
            running = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            // Game Loop
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "TestAppletCycle.stop();");
        if(running) {
            running = false;
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Clean Up Game
    }
}
```

Now to restart the applet you only need to stop and start the applet.